# My SQL Server Agent job is running for long time and failing with Login issues

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, sql-server-agent, sql-authentication

Please see the logs shown below for more information:

```
2020-04-23 13:13:56.97 spid10s     Starting up database 'tempdb'.
2020-04-23 13:13:57.42 spid10s     The tempdb database has 4 data file(s).
2020-04-23 13:13:57.42 spid10s     The tempdb database data files are not configured with the same initial size and autogrowth settings. To reduce potential allocation contention, the initial size and autogrowth of the files should be same.
2020-04-23 13:13:57.42 spid25s     The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2020-04-23 13:13:57.42 spid25s     The Database Mirroring endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2020-04-23 13:13:57.44 spid25s     Service Broker manager has started.
2020-04-23 13:13:58.22 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2020-04-23 13:13:58.22 Logon       Login failed for user 'ZA\ZA_DataExtr_DAAD'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'DG4_40'. [CLIENT: 10.50.254.40]
2020-04-23 13:14:00.23 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2020-04-23 13:14:00.23 Logon       Login failed for user 'ZA\ZA_DataExtr_DAAD'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'DG4_40'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2020-04-23 13:14:09.22 Server      Software Usage Metrics is enabled.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you verify that your user is created under Security >> Users of your database as well as Security >> Logins on your instance?

Comment: Hi , Yes. it was running with same User for long time and was successful until the last deployment.

Comment: Hi Ian-Fogelman, User is created under Security. This was created long time ago and was running successfully . We have deployment of code and increased some RAM to the server. From the next day of deployment it is not running as expected. Iam not able to login in SSMS with the User name and password.

Comment: What I suspect is:code deployment might have removed the access for the user in the specific database

Comment: Hi Venkataraman R, where can i check whether the user has access or not. I could see under Secuirty --> Logins --> the user is available.

Comment: Any suggestions please Ian-Fogelman,Venkataraman R

Comment: Can you go to the security (at instance level), under logins, right click >> Properties, check User Mapping make sure that the database specified is in the User Mapping for that login

Comment: Hi Ian-Fogelman,Venkataraman R thanks for helping me. Issue is with SQL authentication and updated the password for Service account and now issue is resolved